# vss pulgin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, visual-sourcesafe

I installed jenkins in windows   64bit version(with java version 64bit)

Downloaded latest VSS Plugin and i am getting this error
Started by user anonymous

FATAL: D:\java\build\hudson\plugins\vss\WEB-INF\lib\com4j.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\java\build\hudson\plugins\vss\WEB-INF\lib\com4j.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

```
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1778)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1674)
```

i installed java 32 bit version still i am getting above error.

please help me..

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Visual+SourceSafe+Plugin?focusedCommentId=37749076#comment-37749076 - your problem exactly. Looks like you have to get rid of 32-bit Java.

Comment: even after installing java 64bit the problem arises

Comment: Yes, I understood that from your question. I think the point is to make sure that the 32-bit version is not getting in the way.

Comment: i solved it my completely removing 64 bit java version and using only 32 bit version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed 64 bit and installed 32 bit java version. it worked for me